# Passing Attributes / objects through an attribute. Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, object, attributes, polymer

Is there a way to pass an array or object through an attribute? like:

```
<div id="myelem" myattr="{ title: 'hello', author: 'mike'}, { title: 'world', author: 'hellen'}, {...}"/>
```

I just tried this using javascript, but only the first object are being returned, i would like to have something like this:

```
for(let i=0; i<this.myattr.length; i++){
  console.log(this.myattr.title);
}
```

Any ideas? Thankyou

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You will have to* use `JSON.parse()` and your string will have to be in a valid JSON-Format.

```js
var element = document.getElementById('myelem')
var attributeContent = element.getAttribute('data-myattr')
var object = JSON.parse(attributeContent)
```

```html
<div id="myelem" data-myattr='[{ "title": "hello", "author": "mike" }, { "title": "world", "author": "hellen" }]' />
```

*You could also do `var object = eval(attributeContent)` without the need of a JSON-String. But have a look at "[Why is using the JavaScript eval function a bad idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/86513/4339170)"

---

Finally I'd like to suggest to use the `<script>` tag instead of a attribute to pass JavaScript-Objects via your HTML-Code:

```
<script>
    var myStuff = [{ title: 'hello', author: 'mike' }, { title: 'world', author: 'hellen' }, {}];
</script>
```

You will then be able to access `myStuff` in your JavaScript-Code

Answer (score 0):

From this

```
<div id="myelem" myattr="[{ title: 'hello', author: 'mike'}, { title: 'world', author: 'hellen'}, {...}]"/>
```

**Get the attribute value**

**1. Javascript**

```
var attr = document.getElementById('myelem').getAttribute('myattr')
```

**2. JQuery**

```
var attr = $('.myelem').attr('myelem')
```

**String to JSON**

```
var obj = JSON.parse(attr)
```

Answer (score 0):

As you tagged your question Polymer - this works for Polymer-elements :

```
<polymer-element object-attribute='{"alt":"json", "q":"chrome"}'>
```

Source : https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax

Tried it for a custom element, it worked as well - unfortunately it does not work for default html-elements (e.g. divs). So maybe defining a custom-element for this might be a solution for you. Otherwise use the answers above ;)